# Camera manipulation

Tags: python

Recently, I've been thinking about working on a mini-project, which is to change the live camera feed. For example, if you go into Skype, the camera records what's in front of it, before sending the input to Skype. Is it possible, to somewhat change the input with Python? This may be impossible or relatively easy, but I'm new to Python, and any help would be appreciated.                                             .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to manipulate live video before passing it to the actual target. **Yes it is possible** and can be classified in the category of deepfake.

I would recommend you to analyze the code base for [faceit_live](https://github.com/alew3/faceit_live) and reverse engineer it, to know more about how it can be done.